# Find $x_N$ such that $ \lim_{N \to \infty} \log\frac{x_N}{N^2} = A $ and $ \lim_{N \to \infty} \frac{1}{N} \log(1 - x_N) = B $

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, algebra-precalculus, asymptotics

I have for some $A,B \in \mathbb{R}$ a sequenc $x_N \in \mathbb{R}$ such that

$$  \lim_{N \to \infty} \log\frac{x_N}{N^2} = A $$ and yet

$$ \lim_{N \to \infty} \frac{1}{N} \log(1 - x_N) = B $$  What is an example of $x_N$ which satisfies both asymptotics?  What is the most susprising is first we have $\frac{1}{N^2}$ decay and in the other we have $\frac{1}{N}$.  There shouldn't be a sequence that satisfies both conditions

Comment: From your first proposition we get that $X_N \sim e^A N^2$, as $N  \to \infty$, then how do you define $\log(1 - x_N)$ since $1 - x_N<0$ for large $N$?

Comment: Assuming $x_N$ is positive, the first limit implies $x_N$ must be greater than 1 at some point, which means that your second limit becomes complex. Otherwise, there's no such $x_N$ that will give you both limits existing simultaneously.

Comment: The position of the $\log$s and the $N$s is important. In particular, the first one is saying you have $N^2$ *growth*. (or the way its written, an additive $log N$ term)